# Could not read repeated tags value from XML using Freemarker

Tags: java, json, xml, freemarker

I am trying to create a Freemarker program to convert XML to JSON . I am not able to read values from the list of values from the repeated tags of a xml .
Am not able to figure out why i could not read value from repeated tags .

```
<#assign DEALS = body[".//DEALS"]>
{
loans:  [
<#list DEALS as d>
    {
        <#assign PROPERTY = d[".//PROPERTY"]>
        propAddress1: ${PROPERTY[".//AddressLineText"]}
    }
</#list>
]
```

}

```
<MESSAGE>
<DEAL_SETS>
    <DEALS>
        <DEAL>
         <PROPERTY>
        <ADDRESS>
         <AddressLineText>1111</AddressLineText>
        </ADDRESS>
        </PROPERTY>
        </DEAL>
        <DEAL>
         <PROPERTY>
        <ADDRESS>
         <AddressLineText>2222</AddressLineText>
        </ADDRESS>
        </PROPERTY>
        </DEAL>
        <DEAL>
         <PROPERTY>
        <ADDRESS>
         <AddressLineText>3333</AddressLineText>
        </ADDRESS>
        </PROPERTY>
        </DEAL>
    </DEALS>
</DEAL_SET>
</MESSAGE>

Output
{
 "loans": []
}

Expected output
{
"loans": [
{propAddress1: 1111},
{propAddress1: 2222},
{propAddress1: 3333}
]
}
```

Comment: Xpath should be `.//ADDRESS/AddressLineText`

Comment: Please add as Answer , i will accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath should be `.//ADDRESS/AddressLineText`

Answer (score 0):

A problem in your sample code is that in `<#list DEALS as d>`, `DEALS` is the set of `DEALS` elements (which you have exactly 1). Same logic as in XSLT. Therefore `d` will be the `DEALS` element, not a `DEAL` element, and `DEALS` has no `PROPERTY` child. So what you want to list is `DEALS.DEAL`, which is the set of all the `DEAL` elements inside the (single) `DEALS` elements.

Also I'm not sure why you are using `//`. It works, but generally you care what the parents are, so assuming `body` corresponds to the root element (`MESSAGE`), maybe just use this:

```
{
  loans:  [
  <#list body.DEAL_SETS.DEALS.DEAL as DEAL>
    {
      propAddress1: ${DEAL.PROPERTY.ADDRESS.AddressLineText}
    }
  </#list>
  ]
}
```

(If `body` is really the XML document instead, then of course you write `body.MESSAGES.DEAL_SETS.DEALS.DEAL` instead.)

Also, you probably want to quote the address, for which you can use `<#ftl output_format="JSON">` on the top, and then `${DEAL.PROPERTY.ADDRESS.AddressLineText?c}` (this requires FreeMarker 2.3.32).